# Can we avoid creating a local variable if an optional argument is not PRESENT?

Tags: module, fortran, subroutine, optional-arguments

I am having a problem with the `PRESENT` statement with Fortran 95. Currently I am using Silverfrost's Plato and their FTN95 compiler (in "Release Win32" mode). What I wanted to do is to create a subroutine `SUB(a,b)`, where `b` is an optional variable. So far so good, but the problem arises when I try to give a new value to `b` with `if (.NOT. present(b)) b=0`. This is the code:

```
module MOD
contains
  subroutine SUB(a,b)
  implicit none
  integer :: a
  integer,optional :: b
  if (.NOT. present(b)) b=0
  print*, a,b
  end subroutine SUB
end module MOD

program TEST
use MOD
implicit none

integer :: i=2, j=1

call SUB(i,j)
call SUB(i)
call SUB(j)

end program TEST
```

Is there an elegant way out of this situation, or do I really need to create another variable, `b_aux` for instance, and then use the following code?:

```
if (present(b)) then
  b_aux=b
  else
    b_aux=0
endif
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use a non-existent variable, so an approach such as the auxiliary local variable is needed.

Comment: This feature is quite misleading since many languages that have optional arguments also have a way to use them (usually with initialized values). But indeed, section 12.4.1.6 of Fortran 2003 states:
***A dummy argument that is not optional shall be present. An optional dummy
argument that is not present is subject to the following restrictions:
(1) If it is a data object, it shall not be referenced or be defined. If it is of a type for which
default initialization is specified for some component, the initialization has no effect. [...]***