# Segmentation fault with optional arguments in Fortran functions

Tags: function, fortran, optional-parameters

I can use Fortran optional argumenrs with subroutines with `intent(in)` and `intent(inout)`, but with functions optional arguments work only with `intent(in)`, right? With `intent(inout)` I get segmentation faults in the following code:

```
real function foo(x, tol) 
    real, intent(in) :: x
    real, optional, intent(inout) :: tol
    if( .not. present(tol) ) tol = 1e-6
    !...
end function foo
```

Comment: inout should work see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121954/fortran-90-presence-of-optional-arguments

Comment: Maybe the segfault comes from not testing for presence of the argument?

Comment: Maybe you should post a minimal (not) working example...

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem, I used the variable even when not present on the fourth line (in `tol = 1e-6`):

```
real function foo(x, tol) 
    real, intent(in) :: x
    real, optional, intent(inout) :: tol
    if( .not. present(tol) ) tol = 1e-6
    !...
end function foo
```

But I would like to use it even when not present and set a default value, like when in C++ we do something like that

```
double foo(double x, double tol=1e-6)
```

Unfortunately, it seems it is not possible in Fortran.

Comment: You can't define/assign/use an optional argument that is not present. You have to use another variable. For example, name you optional var *opt_tol*, and define *tol* in your program (*if present(opt_tol) then tol=opt_tol else tol=default value*). See section 12.4.1.6 of the [Fortran 2003 standard](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/04/04-007.pdf).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302083/fortran-95-present-statement-using-ftn95-and-plato

Comment: A frequent mistake of those just learning about OPTIONAL is not realizing that the caller of a procedure with OPTIONAL requires an explicit interface to the called routine. See http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/275071#comment-1548437 and http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/01/05/doctor-fortran-gets-explicit-again for more info.